# Create own colorbar for networkx plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, networkx

I have the following problem which I couldn't solve although I spend now several hours for it and thought it would be easy. Basically what I am doing is plotting networks. Each node has a value between 0 and 1. Now I color each node according to its value. 0 would correspond to a red node and 1 to a green node. I do this by the follwing code:

```
for x in range(gn):
    G.add_node(x)
    cn = value[x]
    cn *= 100
    if cn == 100:
        cn = 99
    if cn < 50:
        # green to yellow
        cg = math.floor(255 * (cn / 50))
        cr = 255
    else:
        # yellow to red
        cg = 255
        cr = math.floor(255 * ((50 - cn % 50) / 50))
    cb = 0
    color_map.append('#%02x%02x%02x' % (cr, cg, cb))
```

And then later in the code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx.draw(G, pos, width=weights, node_color=color_map, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Now I just want to have a colorbar beside the network, so that the observer of the plot has an overview which color to which value corresponds. I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance :) 
(The colorbar should start from 0 to 1,even in the event, that there are also nodes with values above 0.5 or so.)

Edit: Minimal working example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import math

gn = 20
color_map = []
G = nx.Graph()
value = numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, gn)
for x in range(gn):
    G.add_node(x)
    cn = value[x]
    cn *= 100
    if cn == 100:
        cn = 99
    if cn < 50:
        # green to yellow
        cg = math.floor(255 * (cn / 50))
        cr = 255
    else:
        # yellow to red
        cg = 255
        cr = math.floor(255 * ((50 - cn % 50) / 50))
    cb = 0
    color_map.append('#%02x%02x%02x' % (cr, cg, cb))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color=color_map, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please separate graph creation from colormapping and provide a minimal example that has `gn` or `G` defined?!

Comment: Did a minimal example. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use matplotlib's custom colormap abilities to make this a little easier.  See for example http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html.

Here is how you might use that with networkx.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy

gn = 20
G = nx.Graph()
value = numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, gn)
G.add_nodes_from(range(gn))

# create colormap
cdict = {'red':   ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

         'green':  ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),

         'blue': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
        }
green_yellow_red = LinearSegmentedColormap('GYR', cdict)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color=value, cmap=green_yellow_red)
# edges = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos) # no edges in this graph
plt.colorbar(nodes)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the `cdict` values? Which is to say, how do you determine that the highest value, `1.0`, is associated with `green`?

Comment: Check the comments at the linked reference http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html for some discussion on the values.